# 405 Error while creating a channel in Discord using Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am getting a `405: Method Not Allowed` error when I try to create a channel.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'),
    dotenv = require('dotenv').config()

const client = new Discord.Client()
const server = new Discord.Guild(client)

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot Online!')
})

client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return

    message.channel.send(`Hello ${message.author}, how are you?`)
})

server.channels
    .create('test', {
        parent: 'test-channels',
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

And this is the exact error:

```sh
DiscordAPIError: 405: Method Not Allowed
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Dispatch\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Dispatch\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async GuildChannelManager.create (D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Dispatch\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildChannelManager.js:112:18) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/guilds/channels',
  code: 0,
  httpStatus: 405
}
```

I have given the bot administrator permission in the server, so that should not be an issue. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Are you sure the token you are using is correct?

Comment: Yes @DJ, I am. How is the client command working then?

Comment: I would suggest getting the guild using its id, `client.guilds.cache.get('the-guild-id-here');` and then doing whatever you want to do with it in the ready event.

Comment: Ok, how can I get the id for a guild? @DJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest getting the guild using its ID this way and then doing whatever you want with it in the ready event:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot Online!')
    const server = client.guilds.cache.get('the-server-id-here');
    server.channels
    .create('test', {
        parent: 'id-of-the-parent-category',
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
})
```

To manually get the ID of a server, follow the below mentioned steps:

1. Go to User Settings > Advanced in Discord.
2. Turn on Developer Mode.
3. Right click the icon of any server, and click on 'Copy ID'.
4. Paste it wherever necessary!

> Note- The parent of a channel must be an ID or a Channel Object.

Comment: How do I get server ids?

Comment: Ah, but I found the way to get it from the code. `client.guilds.cache.map((guild) => console.log(guild.id))`

Comment: That would log the IDs of all servers the bot is in. If your bot is intended to be in a few servers, you can use this too!

Comment: Yes, this is just me getting myself familiar with the library. But, now it has introduced a new error. `Invalid Form Body
parent_id: Value "test-channels" is not snowflake.`

Comment: Does the category test-channels exist in the server?

Comment: Hey, so I asked this is the discord server of discord.js and they pointed out that the parent needs to be an ID of the parent.

Comment: How did I not notice that! That's correct. The Parent must be the ID or the channel object.

Comment: Hey, so I have edited the answer to fulfill my original question intention.